# Is there a conflict between nginx and macOS Ventura 13.5?

Tags: nginx, macos-ventura

A few months back I made an update of macOS and suddenly all my nginx was broken.
I couldn't event start localhost:8080.
After some days trying to figure out what happened, after cleaning all my nginx, reinstall it again and again I finally found some comment on the internet that the problem was coming from the version of my macOS (I couldn't find the article this time, sorry).

Two days ago I had the same issue with my nginx and after 2 days of struggling I remember I just made a new macOS update to Ventura 13.5.

Is there an issue between this version of macOS and nginx ? And if so what is it and how could I fix it ?

What I tried:

- restart nginx

  - `brew services restart nginx` then `curl localhost:8080` => `Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server`
  - `brew services reload nginx` same problem
- uninstall and install nginx

  - `brew uninstall nginx`
  - I did all the `rm -rf` asked to complete the uninstallation
  - `brew install nginx`
  - `curl localhost:8080` => `Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server`